# Default/Optional arguements in class in Racket?

Tags: arguments, scheme, default, racket

I'd like my program to put a default value in an argument when the user doesn't type it. 
My code so far:

```
    (define nodo%
     (class object%
     (init INFO)
     (init HIJOS)
     (init VISITADO?)
     (define info INFO)
     (define hijos HIJOS) 
     (define visitado? VISITADO?)
     (super-new)))
```

The arguemen't I'd like to make default is VISITADO?. (Spanish for visited)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`init` allows for such default arguments:

```
#lang racket
(define nodo%
     (class object%
     (init INFO)
     (init HIJOS)
     (init [VISITADO? #f])
     (define info INFO)
     (define hijos HIJOS) 
     (define visitado? VISITADO?)
     (define/public (get-visitado?)
       visitado?)
     (super-new)))

(define n1 (new nodo% [INFO 'a] [HIJOS 'b]))
(send n1 get-visitado?) ; #f
(define n2 (new nodo% [INFO 'a] [HIJOS 'b] [VISITADO? #t]))
(send n2 get-visitado?) ; #t
```

By the way, you can also use `init-field` for what you are doing with it:

```
#lang racket
(define nodo%
  (class object%
    (init-field info
                hijos
                [visitado? #f])
    (super-new)))

(define n1 (new nodo% [info 'a] [hijos 'b]))
(get-field visitado? n1) ; #f
(define n2 (new nodo% [info 'a] [hijos 'b] [visitado? #t]))
(get-field visitado? n2) ; #t
```

See [the documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/createclass.html?q=init-field#%28form._%28%28lib._racket/private/class-internal..rkt%29._init-field%29%29).